# How can i avoid the use of lists of comprehension, which are too expensive in terms of memory?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

I have three lists of dataframes, for example A, B, C, (7k columns and 5k rows each) and i need to create another list of dataframes using a function, let's call it 'FT', which has three datasets in input. The first element of the list has to be the result of FT(A[0],B[0],C[0]), the second one FT(A[1],B[1],C[1]) and so on. At the beggining i tried using lists of comprehension but beacuse also A,B and C are the results of applying a function to other datasets it was tooo expensive in terms of memory occupation: "

```
Unable to allocate 1.13 GiB
```

```
def F1(a):
    a=pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([a.columns,a]))
    a=a.astype('int')
    return a

mO=[F1(a) for a in list1]

def F2(d):
    N = pd.DataFrame(d)
    N.iloc[0,:]=[abs(number) for number in N.iloc[0,:]]
    N_f.columns=N_f.iloc[0]
    N=N.iloc[1:]
    return N


diFF=[F2(b) for b in mO]

def F3(d,c):
    comb=itertools.permutations(d.columns,2)
    aC=list(comb)
    N=pd.DataFrame()
    N = pd.concat([d[a]+d[b] for a,b in aC],axis=1)
    N.columns=N.iloc[0]
    N=N.iloc[1:]
    N.columns=c.columns
    return N


soMM=[F3(d,c) for d,c in zip(mO,list(diFF))]


def F4(a,b,d):
    Ch=a**2
    Nu=Ch.subtract(b)
    De=b*(b-1)
    P=Nu/De
    P=P.sort_index(ascending=True,axis=1)
    H=P.groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()
    H1=H/d.iloc[0,-1]
    return H1

Final=[F4(a,b,c) for a,b,c in zip(diFF,soMM,mO)]
```

I tried using map and lambda functions but i am able to create properly mO and soMM lists but when i have to create the last two and i try to list their generated elemnts they return blank lists.

```
mO=map(lambda a: F1(a),list1)
diFF=map(lambda b: F2(b), list(mO))
soMM=map(lambda c,d: F3(c,d),zip(list(mO),list(diFF)))
phi=map(lambda e,f,g: F4(e,f,g), zip(list(diFF),list(soMM),list(mO))))
```

Comment: List comprehensions don't cause memory use.  You're creating a list of multiple dataframes.  Those lists use up memory no matter how you create them.  Your map/lambda uses the same memory as a list comp.

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert a `map` to a list multiple times. The first time will exhaust the iterator, so the others will get an empty list.

You should avoid converting the maps to lists at all; this way, the functions will be called as needed on each individual item, without consuming memory to hold all the results. But since you can't reuse a map, you'll need to duplicate them.

There's no need to wrap all your function calls in `lambda`. Just pass the function directly as the `map()` argument. And you don't need to call `zip()`, you can pass multiple iterables to `map()` and they'll be used for the corresponding arguments to the function (if you do use `zip()`, the `lambda` should just take one argument, and it will have to unpack it into several variables).

```
m0_1 = map(F1, list1)
m0_2 = map(F1, list1)
m0_3 = map(F1, list1)
m0_4 = map(F1, list1)
diFF_1 = map(F2, m0_1)
diFF_2 = map(F2, m0_2)
soMM = map(F3, m0_3, diFF_1)
final = map(F4, diFF_2, soMM, m0_4)
```